# Unity dash alternative for fluxbox

Tags: unity-dash, fluxbox

Recently I've installed fluxbox window manager on my lUbuntu. Everything works fine but I'm having trouble finding some of my applications. Is there  some kind of alternative for unity dash for fluxbox ? Perhaps something lighter that comes with a tray icon?

Comment: "I'm having trouble finding some of my applications" <<< please explain that.

Comment: Anyway, I use `Kupfer` from the repos.